# Sql Query Create a new Table

Tags: sql

Can anyone offered syntax for a sql query that takes an already created table and inserts some of the data into a new table with a new id(primary key)? So far I tried this

```
SELECT ((ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY), column1, column2, column3)
INTO table_name
FROM table_name
```

I keep coming up with a syntax error.

Comment: Just for understanding: Why don't you just copy the 'from'-table and change the primary key afterwards with an "alter-table" statement?

Comment: You can't insert a column declaration into a table row. And your example is selecting into table_name from table_name - you might want to update your example to make it clearer that you (do you?) mean INTO target_table FROM source_table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_table
(Column1, Column2 . . . )

SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM old_table
```

Don't include the identity column (the primary key with the auto-generated numbers) in the insert list.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
INTO table_name_new
FROM table_name_old
```

use like this

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO newtable (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT (column1, column2, column3) 
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make it like below, Aa new id will be automatically created while inserting the record

```
insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from table2;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx), the IDENTITY property will transfer through with a `SELECT INTO` clause, but constraints will not. That means you can create a new table with an IDENTITY column if you include the original IDENTITY column from your source table, but the column in the new table won't be a primary key.

The sane way to do this is to use ALTER TABLE after the table is created, as @Kai has suggested.